# Erro when I apply stash

Tags: git

I just stash before pull a commit. I want to unstash what I made:

Here is the stash list:

```
git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on master: 1edd599 add ECHAP key
stash@{1}: WIP on master: 1f38506 synchronize QSlider & QDouble/SpinBox set Min/max values set default values
```

And the error I have when I want to unstash my work:

```
    git stash show -p stash@{1} | git apply -R
<stdin>:156: trailing whitespace.
       <number>1</number>
<stdin>:165: trailing whitespace.
             <number>1</number>
error: le patch a échoué : BGE_GUI.pro:32
error: BGE_GUI.pro : le patch ne s'applique pas
error: le patch a échoué : include/CommonGUI.h:1
error: include/CommonGUI.h : le patch ne s'applique pas
error: le patch a échoué : include/MainWindow.h:6
error: include/MainWindow.h : le patch ne s'applique pas
error: le patch a échoué : mainwindow.ui:63
error: mainwindow.ui : le patch ne s'applique pas
error: le patch a échoué : object/MainUnit/MainController.cpp:8
error: object/MainUnit/MainController.cpp : le patch ne s'applique pas
error: le patch a échoué : object/MainUnit/MainController.h:6
error: object/MainUnit/MainController.h : le patch ne s'applique pas
error: le patch a échoué : object/MainUnit/MainModel.cpp:14
error: object/MainUnit/MainModel.cpp : le patch ne s'applique pas
error: le patch a échoué : object/MainUnit/MainModel.h:10
error: object/MainUnit/MainModel.h : le patch ne s'applique pas
error: le patch a échoué : object/MainUnit/MainView.cpp:17
error: object/MainUnit/MainView.cpp : le patch ne s'applique pas
error: le patch a échoué : object/MainUnit/MainView.h:1
error: object/MainUnit/MainView.h : le patch ne s'applique pas
error: object/PlayerUnit/PlayerController.cpp : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
error: object/PlayerUnit/PlayerController.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
error: object/PlayerUnit/PlayerModel.cpp : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
error: object/PlayerUnit/PlayerModel.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
error: object/PlayerUnit/PlayerView.cpp : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
error: object/PlayerUnit/PlayerView.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
error: le patch a échoué : object/PreviewUnit/PreviewController.cpp:1
error: object/PreviewUnit/PreviewController.cpp : le patch ne s'applique pas
error: le patch a échoué : object/PreviewUnit/PreviewController.h:1
error: object/PreviewUnit/PreviewController.h : le patch ne s'applique pas
error: object/PreviewUnit/PreviewModel.cpp : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
error: object/PreviewUnit/PreviewModel.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
error: object/PreviewUnit/PreviewView.cpp : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
error: object/PreviewUnit/PreviewView.h : Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
error: le patch a échoué : object/RenderingUnit/RenderingController.cpp:16
error: object/RenderingUnit/RenderingController.cpp : le patch ne s'applique pas
error: le patch a échoué : object/RenderingUnit/RenderingController.h:28
error: object/RenderingUnit/RenderingController.h : le patch ne s'applique pas
error: le patch a échoué : object/RenderingUnit/RenderingModel.cpp:5
error: object/RenderingUnit/RenderingModel.cpp : le patch ne s'applique pas
error: le patch a échoué : object/RenderingUnit/RenderingModel.h:16
error: object/RenderingUnit/RenderingModel.h : le patch ne s'applique pas
error: le patch a échoué : object/RenderingUnit/RenderingView.cpp:40
error: object/RenderingUnit/RenderingView.cpp : le patch ne s'applique pas
error: le patch a échoué : object/RenderingUnit/RenderingView.h:16
error: object/RenderingUnit/RenderingView.h : le patch ne s'applique pas
error: le patch a échoué : src/MainWindow.cpp:4
error: src/MainWindow.cpp : le patch ne s'applique pas
error: le patch a échoué : src/main.cpp:5
```

I don't understand why the patch don't apply properly.
How can I simply remove refind all the file I stash?

Comment: If you want to apply `stash@{1}`, why are you running `git stash show -p stash@{1} | git apply -R` rather than just `git stash apply stash@{1}`? The show-pipe-to-apply-dash-R attempts to *remove* that change.

Comment: I made a modification and I don't commit it. I made a stash locally , I pull the project and I modify it with no merge. This is the reason why. I finally force the modification by pop the last pull and commit my first stash and merge it with the modification on the server.  Thank you @torek